# Method inside of React Class not executing

Tags: react-native

I currently have a component in React Native

```
export default class Category extends Component {}
```

For the sake of shortening the code I won't include everything but the code below is inside this class.

I have the following method which works when executed on a button:

```
  dbGetValues(subCatId) {
    let subValues = [];
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM dr_template_relational '
        + ' INNER JOIN  dr_report_categorie_values on dr_report_categorie_values.id = dr_template_relational.value_id'
        + ' WHERE dr_template_relational.subcategory_id = ' + subCatId + ' AND dr_template_relational.template_id = ' + this.state.currentTemplateId,
        [],
      (trans, result) => {
        const sqLiteResults = result.rows._array;

        sqLiteResults.forEach(el => {
          subValues.push({ subCategoryId: subCatId, values: el.value_id, name: el.name, narrative: el.narrative })
        })
      });
    },
    (err) => console.error(err),
    () => {
      return subValues;
    }
  );
  }
```

Then I have this method.  In the following method I am attempting to execute: `dbGetValues()` . the error I get is that dbGetValues is NOT . function

```
  dbGetTemplateOptions() {
    let dataArray = [];
    let subcategories = this.state.subcategories;
    console.log(subcategories);
    subcategories.forEach(function (item) {
      dataArray.push({
        title: item.name,
        content: <Text>{this.dbGetValues(item.subCatId)}</Text>
      });
    });

    return dataArray;
  }
```

this.dbGetValues works inside of other methods but when placed in the forEach it's giving me this error.  I know it has to do with scope but I don't understand why.  Shouldn't it work since I'm in the react class?  I've read tons of articles on "this" but I still don't have it down.
I even tried binding `this.dbGetValues = this.dbGetValues.bind(this);`

EDIT: attempted to turn functions into fat arrows:
dbGetTemplateOptions = () => {}
dbGetValues = (subCatId) => {}
Same results.

Comment: Can you try converting all your methods into [arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly certain the issue is that since `dbGetTemplateOptions` is a regular function, it's context is bound when it is called. This means that `this` is not the object you expect it to be.

You can fix it by converting `dbGetTemplateOptions` to an arrow function, so that `this` is always going to be `this object`.

EDIT: I see another issue here.

Your line here:

```
subcategories.forEach(function (item) {
```

uses a `function`. This means when forEach is calling your function, its context gets bound differently. Try changing `function (item) {` to `item => {`

Comment: Changed to this dbGetTemplateOptions = () => { stuff in here } and also same for dbGetValues and still says "dbGetValues" is not a function.  @JClassic

Comment: Are the two functions in the same class? Also, whats the output when you run `console.log(this.dbGetValues)` @FabricioG

Comment: Yes they are @JClassic

Comment: @FabricioG try output the value of `this.dbGetValues`